# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with SPLIT

Tags: split, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to to a split on a String but i get an error : `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=3`

The code is quite simple :

```
String [] partsTimer = dataTempExt.split("'");
Integer lgTimer = partsTimer.length - 1;
for (int i = 0; i <= lgTimer ; ++i)
{
    Log.w("WIDGET",  partsTimer[i] + " with i=" +i);
}
```

`String DataTempExt = "['2019-07-05 18:22:09',27.39],['2019-07-27 16:32:53',27.59],"` in my exemple.

Log :

```
W/WIDGET: 
    [ with i=0
    2019-07-05 18:22:09 with i=1
    ,27.39],[ with i=2
    2019-07-27 16:32:53 with i=3
    ,27.59], with i=4
```

I am trying to get the value with i = 3 : 2019-07-27 16:32:53

But if i do :

```
Log.w("WIDGET Timer i3 = ",  partsTimer[3]);
```

I got this error :

```
 Process: com.evo.evodomo, PID: 19563
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.evo.evodomo.Widget.NewAppWidget: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=3
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3584)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1779)
```

I don't understand why i can get the value in the FOR but not directly with [3]...
Why `partsTimer[i]` with i = 3 is working but not `partsTimer[3]` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are initialising `i = 0` and there are total 3 elements in array `partsTimer` so to fix the issue you should use `partsTimer[2]`

Because array index starts from zero.

Comment: Hum but then partsTimer[3] should be egal to i = 4 which is :
,27.59],
Why i get this error if i = 4 is ok ? There is 5 elements in partsTimer.

Same error with partsTimer[2] :
Unable to start receiver com.evo.evodomo.Widget.NewAppWidget: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=2

Comment: Nope. partsTimer[3] is not equal to i=4 . It's equal to i=3

Comment: partsTimer[0] = [
partsTimer[1] = error
partsTimer[2] = error
partsTimer[3] = error
partsTimer[4] = error
but in the FOR : 
    [ with i=0
    2019-07-05 18:22:09 with i=1
    ,27.39],[ with i=2
    2019-07-27 16:32:53 with i=3
    ,27.59], with i=4

The error say : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1
Why lenght = 1 if there is 5 elements ?